# tortoiseSVN update to new specific version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to update tortoiseSVN to new specific version

For example:
Suppose I have the revision 100 in my environment.
There are two more new revisions in svn (101 and 102)
I want to update my environment to only revision 101 and not to 102

How can I update my local environment to only revision 101?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the TortoiseSVN context menu, select `Update to revision...` (it's between `Resolve...` and `Revert...`).

[image: Screenshot]

Then type the number 101 where it says "Revision".

Comment: Can I skip a version while update?

For example:
I used Update to Revision... to update my environment to 101
Suppose these is a new version 103
I don't want to update 102 (skip 102) and update 103?

Comment: @Peter That's bound to get ugly fast and most likely 102 should have been a branch. You might be able to update to 101, then do a manual merge from just 103. But if you don't branch be *very* careful if you commit to 104 because you may inadvertently undo 102's changes (or worse).

Comment: As far as Subversion is concerned, revision 103 is built upon 102 and you can't easily get 103 without also getting 102 (you can get 103, then reverse-merge 102's changes, but that will get ugly in a hurry). It sounds like you need to take a step back and re-evaluate how you manage your development process and updates to your environments if this is a regular occurrence.